# Surpassing same-origin policy with server side requests - NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, express, request, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to achieve a structure described in [this article - "Using a Web Proxy"](https://www.sitepoint.com/working-around-origin-policy/) using a NodeJS server with Express. I need to access the html of an embedded iframe which is of course impossible due to same-origin policy. As a workaround, I figured that I could simply request the iframe on my server and then pass it on to the client.

I made an entry point on my server called `/getIframe`.

When the client requests `/getIframe`, my server makes a [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to the desired location and saves the page as a html document (using [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)) which is then sent back to the client. This works fine but all scripts/css included in the html are not being passed as [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) only gets the html.

So, I downloaded the scripts/css manually and voilà, it's working. Here is the code.

```
app.get('/getIframe', function(req, res, next) {
  request("http://www.iframeurl.com/something", function(error, response, body) {
    fs.writeFileSync('iframe.html', body, 'utf8');
    var html = fs.readFileSync('iframe.html', 'utf8')
    res.send(html);
  });
})
```

Invoked like this

```
<iframe src={"/getIframe"}></iframe>
```

I now have the behaviour I was looking for but the need of manually downloading the script is not ideal.

Is there a way to request a page on a Node server and just pass it on to the client with all the content (scripts, css etc.)?

What I'm looking for is something like

```
app.get('/getIframe', function(req, res, next) {
  request("http://www.iframeurl.com/something", function(error, response, body) {
    //pass on the requested page in a response with res.send(thePage) or render it with res.render(..)
  });
})
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried the answer provided by @Dafuck and although it is a better way of redirecting to a desired address, the resource issue still remains.

@Dafuck suggested the following solution

```
app.use('/getIframe', function(req, res, next) {
    request.get({ url: "http://www.iframeurl.com/something" }).pipe(res);
})
```

Which also can be achieved with

```
app.use('/getIframe', function(req, res, next) {
    req.pipe(request("http://www.iframeurl.com/something")).pipe(res);
})
```

Both solutions redirect to the desired address from which the html is forwarded. And that's nice. The problem is that all scripts/links included in `<head>` of the retrieved html are then pointing to the server address like `http://localhost:3000` where they obviously don't exist.

Example: The html of `http://www.example.com` looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv=content-type content="text/html; charset=utf-8" lang=en>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width" />
  <link href="somecss.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="somejs.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Example
</body>

</html>
```

Using either of the two methods mentioned above, requesting `/getIframe` from my server will return the correct html of `http://www.example.com` **but** the browser will try to fetch `somejs.js`and `somecss.css` from `http://localhost:3000` and as mentioned before, fail as all resources are found on `http://www.emample.com`.

I've tried yet another approach using [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(
  {
    prependPath: false,
    ignorePath: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    xfwd: true,
  }
);

app.all("/getIframe", function(req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: "http://www.example.com"});
});
```

Sadly, it seems like the last solution is a dead end as I get a strange response from the source I'm trying to fetch. My guess is that the source is preventing addition of x-forward headers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pipe the result of request to res in order to return the page in the response

```
request.post({ url: 'http://www.example.com', form: { foo: 'bar' }}).pipe(res);
```

Which is mainly similar to this:

```
request.get({url: "http://yolo"},function(err, response, body){
   if(err) return res.end();

   res.write(body);
   res.setStatus(response.statusCode);
   res.setHeader("Content-type", response.headers['content-type']);
   return res.end();
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.